# Get all items from custom content type in Fast Search

Tags: content-type, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint, keywordquery

I want to get all items of a custom content type while using fast search. I want to use keyword search but i also could use fql. 
Can somebody show me how to do this in code? I'm getting restults for standard content types when using something like Querytest = "contenttype:document".

[Update] The problem was that i only started a crawl on the content source for the Fast Search Query Server not for the connector.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% on setting up FAST, but in Enterprise Search, you have to modify the crawled property `ows_contenttype` to include the values in the search index, and the managed property `ContentType` should return the values, and allow you to search by it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);

keywordQuery.QueryText = "ContentType:Document";
keywordQuery.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
keywordQuery.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
ResultTableCollection results = keywordQuery.Execute();
 
ResultTable resultsTable = results[ResultType.RelevantResults];
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.TableName = "Results";
dataTable.Load(resultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

You can then access the results from within the DataTable returned.